# variable not taking in consideration with velocity

Tags: velocity

I want to generate java class.
I create a template with velocity

```
@Repository
public class $className extends BaseRepository<$bean, $searchDto> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public $className(EntityManager em) {
        super($bean.class, em);
    }

}
```

If I pass this value

```
className=UsersRepositoryImpl
bean=Users
searchDto=UsersSearch
```

I get

```
@Repository
public class UsersRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepository<Users, UsersSearch> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    public UsersRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
        super(class java.lang.String, em);
    }

}
```

seem like a issue with $bean.class

tried "$bean.class" but get same issue

Edit

put {} around work
${bean}

Comment: What you are passing is string when you do .class its getting the string class .

Comment: change `super($bean.class, em);` to `super($bean#[[.]]#class, em);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
${bean}.class
```

which tells the velocity processor that ${bean} is the velocity variable and .class is just static text of the template. Othherwise he will interpret $bean.class as one expression, your $bean is a String and $bean.class is therefore printed using the toString method of the String's Class object.